# Is subjunctive mood used after would like that

Tags: verbs

Which one of the following two sentences is correct

> 1. I would like that you **finish** the project on time.

> 2. I would like that you **finished** the project on time.

In my book second one is correct but I think first one is correct, please help me clear my doubt

Thanks

Comment: 1. is wrong because the verb "like" does not license (permit) a subjunctive complement. 2. is best avoided; it's not the subjunctive and it's non-standard, though you may encounter it in casual speech.

Comment: I have not come across native English speakers using 2 either. Rather: **I would like you to finish the project on time.**